# Azure IotHubException comes as 'The connection was closed because another AMQP client opened a receive link' when trying to receive a message

Tags: c#, azure, amqp, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to receive the Azure Device client message as below

```
public async Task<List<string>> RecieveMessage(string correlationId)
        {
            var response = new List<string>();
            InitializeDeviceClient("AMQP");
            var flag = true;
            while (flag)
            {
                Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

                if (receivedMessage == null)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    continue;
                }

                Trace.WriteLine(receivedMessage.CorrelationId.ToString());
                await this.deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
                if (receivedMessage.CorrelationId != correlationId)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                   
                var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());
                response.Add(content);
                flag = false;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

In *ReceiveAsync* method I get the exception as below intermittently when running in VSTS.

Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.IotHubException: error(condition:com.microsoft:link-creation-conflict,description:{"errorCode":409002,"trackingId":"e22773c954504357bcd262ebcf7e6c9e-G:3-TimeStamp:01/28/2021 23:24:27","message":"The connection was closed because another AMQP client opened a receive link. Only one connection is allowed per client identity. To learn more, see [https://aka.ms/iothub409002","timestampUtc":"2021-01-28T23:24:27.2617772Z"},info:[com.microsoft:is-filtered:True]](https://aka.ms/iothub409002%22,%22timestampUtc%22:%222021-01-28T23:24:27.2617772Z%22%7D,info:%5Bcom.microsoft:is-filtered:True%5D)) ---> Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpException: {"errorCode":409002,"trackingId":"e22773c954504357bcd262ebcf7e6c9e-G:3-TimeStamp:01/28/2021 23:24:27","message":"The connection was closed because another AMQP client opened a receive link. Only one connection is allowed per client identity. To learn more, see [https://aka.ms/iothub409002","timestampUtc":"2021-01-28T23:24:27.2617772Z"}](https://aka.ms/iothub409002%22,%22timestampUtc%22:%222021-01-28T23:24:27.2617772Z%22%7D)

StackTrace:

```
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.OpenAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.EndOpen(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.AmqpIoT.AmqpIoTSession.OpenReceivingAmqpLinkAsync(DeviceIdentity deviceIdentity, AmqpSession amqpSession, Nullable`1 senderSettleMode, Nullable`1 receiverSettleMode, String deviceTemplate, String moduleTemplate, String linkSuffix, String correlationId, TimeSpan timeout)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.AmqpIoT.AmqpIoTSession.OpenReceivingAmqpLinkAsync(DeviceIdentity deviceIdentity, AmqpSession amqpSession, Nullable`1 senderSettleMode, Nullable`1 receiverSettleMode, String deviceTemplate, String moduleTemplate, String linkSuffix, String correlationId, TimeSpan timeout)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.AmqpIoT.AmqpIoTSession.OpenMessageReceiverLinkAsync(DeviceIdentity deviceIdentity, TimeSpan timeout)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.AmqpIoT.AmqpUnit.EnsureMessageReceivingLinkAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.AmqpIoT.AmqpUnit.ReceiveMessageAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.Amqp.AmqpTransportHandler.ReceiveAsync(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.ErrorDelegatingHandler.ExecuteWithErrorHandlingAsync[T](Func`1 asyncOperation)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.RetryDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<<ReceiveAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.RetryDelegatingHandler.ReceiveAsync(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
       at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.InternalClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
       at 
    RecieveMessage(String correlationId) in ....file.cs:line 487
```

What could be the reason for this?

Is is someway InitializeDeviceClient is called multiple times?

That method implementation is as below

```
public void InitializeDeviceClient(string connType)
        {
            bool setFlag = _fixture.UseCertificate;
            if (setFlag)
            {
                try
                {
                    var initialPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), Constants.PathCertPath.ToString());
                    DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(initialPath);
                    FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*");
                    var cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(initialPath, filesInDir[0].ToString())),
                     "123",
                     X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
                    var auth = new DeviceAuthenticationWithX509Certificate(Path.GetFileName(filesInDir[0].ToString().Replace(".pfx", "")), cert);
                    if (deviceClient == null)
                    {
                        switch (connType.ToUpper())
                        {
                            case ConnectionTypes.Amqp:
                                deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(_fixture.IoTHubHostName, auth, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Amqp_Tcp_Only);
                                break;
                            case ConnectionTypes.Mqtt:
                                deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(_fixture.IoTHubHostName, auth, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Mqtt);
                                break;
                            case ConnectionTypes.Https:
                                deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(_fixture.IoTHubHostName, auth, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Http1);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error in sample: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Most likely you're either trying to create multiple DeviceClients with the same credentials, or you're running a Device/DeviceClient somewhere else. It might also be helpful to include the implementation of InitializeDeviceClient.

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer added that as well

Comment: Does the below answer helps you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not closing the connection made and recreating the connection. You error message says that [**`409002 LinkCreationConflict`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-error-409002-linkcreationconflict) error has occured.
[image]

You can **Close the Connection after use** OR in `dispose` function by using `await DeviceClient.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`.